# Hostings support SSH with price lower than 5 USD

Tags: looking-for-hosting, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking for some hostings support [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) with price lower than 5 USD.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you be more specific about what type of hosting you are looking for? Also would that be $5 per month?

Comment: @emddudley : whatever, just need SSH. $5 is also OK.

Answer (score 3):

[A Small Orange](http://www.asmallorange.com/hosting/shared/) offer ssh on their shared plans. The "Small" option is $5/month, and if you really want to be cheap the "Tiny" is $25/year(yes, really).

If you want a VPS, your best bet is to grab the feed from [Low End Box](http://www.lowendbox.com/) and wait for something to show up; it's updated all the time. There are several ~$5/mo options listed right now.

Answer (score 1):

Buyvm.net has very reasonable price from $3.50 for a vps on a monthly plan. netcup.de has also good price for about €5.